# Is there a way to locate a segment line in an 837?

Tags: edi, x12

I'm having some issues isolating errors in my 837. The system that's interpreting my 837 is giving me a segment where the error is found, but since I have so many claims (and therefore segments), I can't just count the segments until I get to the one I need.

Is there some way of finding a specific segment line? I know the general area the segment line is in (based on the an account number the error is listed under), but I have no way of knowing which of the segments has the errors.

Here's an example of what I mean. There's revenue codes listed after the SV2, then a corresponding code, then the cost of that code.

```
SV2*0450*HC:96368*100.00*UN*1~
DTP*472*D8*20171204~
LX*13~
SV2*0450*HC:96371*700.00*UN*5~
DTP*472*D8*20171204~
LX*14~
SV2*0450*HC:96372*50.00*UN*1~
DTP*472*D8*20171204~
LX*15~
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [X12 Parser](https://github.com/imsweb/x12-parser/)

```
loop.getLoop("2400", 0).getSegment("SV1").getElementValue("SV101")
```

can get you the value needed.

For more examples look at [X12ReaderTest](https://github.com/imsweb/x12-parser/blob/master/src/test/java/com/imsweb/x12/reader/X12ReaderTest.java)